# Can I print POS or Thermal print using JavaScript or Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, thermal-printer, pos

I am making a website for a ticket booking system. Now I have a requirement of direct print using a thermal printer (like a restaurant bill).

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the [printer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/printer) package is what you are looking for?

Comment: I have a website in react js, I want to print tickets exacllty like restaurant billing system. 
can it possible in website or need an application for thermal print?

Comment: The website is restricted by the browser implementation of [print()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print), if you can get the DOM to look how you want, and the browser recognizes the printer, than you can do it from the browser. If not, you will need application that has access to OS print apis